Error: [nuxt] [request error] [unhandled] [500] Cannot destructure property 'doc' of 'undefined' as it is undefined
I've built a personal Blog page with Nuxt Content & Nuxt Studio.
If I execute nuxt generate command locally everything works like a charm. The problem starts when I try to deploy from Nuxt Studio. It automatically triggers 2 Github Actions. See screenshot:

pages-build-deployment  works. But when it comes to studio nuxt build it fails and  I dont know what is causing the issue.
This is the error log:
It fails in the "generate" step.

Error:  [nuxt] [request error] [unhandled] [500] Cannot destructure property 'doc' of 'undefined' as it is undefined.
screenshot of the error
Any idea what could be causing this error?
